# How to format bibtex keys when exporting from EndNote

Tags: bibtex

I exported citation from EndNote and they don't work.  Why is that?

```
@article{Fox, TA-1991-97,
   author = {Fox, TA},
   title = {Wake characteristics of two circular cylinders arranged perpendicular to each other},
   journal = {Journal of fluids engineering},
   volume = {113},
   number = {1},
   pages = {45-50},
   ISSN = {0098-2202},
   year = {1991},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Comment: What you've posted is an *entry* in the `.bib` file. The first field is the unique key that identifies each entry. It cannot contain spaces or commas.  Is your question about how to *format* the key when it is typeset?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, my way is export endnote into bibtex, and when exporting, I use author_year to the label, (and there is some comma in it)so I need to change the format,right?

Comment: Probably.  I don't know much about EndNote's export function.  But if you can specify the key format, then something just involving just letters and numbers and a few other characters would be best. The following characters are disallowed:  `" "@',\#}{~%` and you also shouldn't use `&^$` (the underscore `_` character can also cause problems.)

Comment: @AlanMunn You should convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exporting citations from other bibliography managers, you need to be able to generate legal cite keys for `bibtex`.   If you can specify the key format, then something just involving just letters and numbers and a few other characters would be best.

The following characters are disallowed:

```
     " "@',\#}{~%
```

and you also shouldn't use `&^$` (the underscore `_` character can also cause problems.)

Comment: Thanks, @AlanMunn I know the reason and then I find other way to put the label not including the comma, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have a lot of references or just loath doing manual repetitive labor, [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net) can be quite helpful for properly formatting from EndNote to BibTeX.

If you don't already have it, you will need the Endnote to BibTeX style (available [here](http://endnote.com/downloads/style/bibtex-export)). Just download that file and double click on it to install it (it should open with EndNote). Then in the library you want to export, go to `File > Export`, then choose `Text Only` and `BibTeX Export`. That will save a `.txt` file.

Once you have that .txt file, open up JabRef, and go to `File > Import into new database`, then select the file you exported from EndNote. This will load your library into JabRef.

JabRef can then automatically create citation keys for all your entries if you go to `Tools > Autogenerate BibTeX keys`. The default format is Lastnameyear (`Smith2013`), but it can be edited in `Options > Preferences > BibTex key generator` by changing the key pattern using the terms [here](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/LabelPatterns.php). For example, you can make the keys appear as `smith13` by changing the pattern to `[auth:lower][shortyear]`.

Once you have your data as you like it, save it as a `.bib` file that can be referenced as needed when compiling your document.

Unfortunately, special characters tend not to export well from EndNote to text format, which can be an issue if you're in a field such as chemistry with lots of special characters in titles. You will most likely need to manually check for errors with special character and format them as plain text or as something recognized by LaTeX. Additionally, if you need special capitalization exceptions (again, common in chemistry for oxidation states and chemical formulas), `{}` need to be added around the text to tell `BibTeX` to hold the capitalization of that text. It is not recommended to place braces around the whole titles as that can cause inconsistencies in the capitalization.

See this wikibooks [entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) for general notes on LaTeX bibliographies and their implementation.

Note, there are other bibliography managers useful for `BibTeX` but I found JabRef to import the poorly formatted export of EndNote well (unlike [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net) which failed to import my exported library), and the automatic key generation was extremely helpful. Some other possible software choices are list in the wikibooks entry [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Helpful_tools)

Comment: Regarding BibDesk, specifically, see my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199760/61839) on how to import EndNote's syntactically invalid BibTeX. If you had a failure, I hope that you reported it so we could improve BibDesk.

Answer (score 1):

This short awk command assigns unique Bibtex labels in numerical order to an endnote file that has been exported as BibTex without unique labels.

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1}{if($1~/^@/){c++}; gsub("{", "{REF:"c",", $1)}' Endnote.bib > EndnoteCorrect.bib
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [plugin for Endnote](https://github.com/JonnoFTW/BibTeX-Label-Creator) that will generate BibTeX labels and is compatible with the built in Endnote BibTeX output style.

Answer (score 0):

Above awk script did not work for me (MacOS). I slightly modified as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1}{if($1~/^@/){c++; gsub("{", "{REF:"c",", $1)};print}' Endnote.bib > EndnoteCorrect.bib
```