# Lost when trying to use bibtex in Mactex

Tags: bibtex, mactex, endnotes

i think my probelm is probably pretty easy to solve. I have done research on the web on how to do it but never really been able to follow through.

I have mactex and endnote running on MacOS 10.9.4

I have generated a BibTex (text only) Export .txt out of Endnote and put it in the same folder as the document I am writing in Mactex (I have named them both the same. So now I have a folder with two files Expose.tex and Expose.txt (the file with all my references out of endnote).

What do I do now? Any hints or to do list greatly appreciated. Sorry for the idiocy...

### Phil

Ok I'm using MacTeX - but I have no gotten so far to knowing that what's missing is that I don't have any labels created for the single references when I export from Endnote. Is there a way to let endnote make labels with 'authoryear' or something like that so I don#t have to manually fill in a label for every reference - and I yes, I do understand this is probably mor e aendnote than a latex question... nevertheless - maybe there is someone here who experienced the same and has found a solution so far.

Comment: Your bibliography file should have `.bib` extension, say `Expose.bib`. You must choose a bibliography style and call it from your main file: \bibliography{Expose}`. Then compile with (pdf)latex, bibtex, (pdf)latex, (pdf)latex.

Comment: Open a terminal window and type `texdoc btxdoc` to access a basic introduction to BibTeX.

Comment: On a different but related matter: Are you considering using the modern and flexible couple called `biblatex` and `biber`?

Comment: What editor are you using to produce your TeX?

Comment: Using MacTeX. Phil

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using OS X and MacTeX, I'll assume you have BibDesk installed or can download it. From the File menu, choose "Open Using Temporary Cite Keys" and select your Endnote-generated .bib file in the dialog. When the file opens, select all items in the main list and choose "Generate Cite Key" from the Publication menu in BibDesk. Save the file, which should now have a valid, unique cite key for each item.