# My bibliography doesn't have a key/id

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm very new so please bear with me. I have just exported my bibliography from Endnote into a `.bib` file. I have put it in the same folder as my Tex file.

Entries look like this:

```
@article{
   author = {Bertrand, M. and Duflo, E. and Mullainathan, S.},
   title = {How Much Should We Trust Difference-In-Differences Estimates?},
   journal = {Quarterly Journal of Economics},
   volume = {119},
   pages = {249-275},
   year = {2004}
}
```

In my TeX file, I have inserted the following code before the \begin{document}:

```
\bibliography{endnotelibrary}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

However, I do not know how to use `cite{}` or `citep{}` as my .bib entries seem to have no key.

```
 @article{**SOMETHING MISSING HERE**
       author = {Bertrand, M. and Duflo, E. and Mullainathan, S.},
```

Anyone knows what code would cite this paper of Bertrand and Duflo in my text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that Endnote missed assigning a key to the item. Add one where you have `**SOMETHING MISSING HERE**`. It can be anything.

Comment: Add a key in the place you've marked, say 'bertrand2004', and then use \cite{bertrand2004} in your .tex file.

Comment: You can just insert your own key there by hand. Or if you want it done automatically, look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145945/how-to-format-bibtex-keys-when-exporting-from-endnote).

Comment: (Can't edit earlier comment) note that the entry key must end with a comma, just like the other fields of the entry.

Comment: I wonder if this is really on-topic: the failure to export correctly is an EndNote issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an error that occurred in Endnote, rather than among TeX and friends. If you can't get Endnote to produce keys, you'll have to insert them manually in the bib file.

Comment: Thanks egreg and @jon for your help. I have less than 100 entries so I will do it manually.

Comment: @Mico I see your point and Endnote is "responsible" for this fail. However, this can be useful to many people making the transition to LaTeX. I don't see any harm in keep it.

Comment: @user3507584 - Closing a posting on this site is *not* the same as deleting it. Even if this posting gets closed, it'll still be visible to Google searches with the keywords "endnote", "latex" and "missing key".

Comment: ah OK, so then go ahead! :-)