# Is it possible to cite without a citation key?

Tags: bibtex

I exported my .bib file from EndNote into LaTeX. However, there is no citation key for references. Do I have to add citation keys (manually) for each reference to be able to cite them within my document?

Comment: Yes, you need a key. LaTeX can't read your mind, it needs some way to identify the citation.

Comment: :) I've just wondered if I can use (somehow) existing author names within author field.

Comment: Did you try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207219/14500 ?

Comment: Are you looking to list every entry in the bib file in the references section of your document, without needing to cite each and every entry explicitly somewhere in the body of the document?

Comment: Actually, it would be better to list each of them in the references section.

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is simply to include each and every entry in the bib file(s) mentioned in the `\bibliography` instruction, regardless of whether or not they are `\cite`d explicitly somewhere in your document, simply issue the command

```
\nocite{*}
```

somewhere in the body of the document, i.e., somewhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: have you tried it? if there are no citation keys (or label, e.g. `@article{,`) in the bibtex file, you will end with a bibliography with only one entry.

Comment: @Guido - I have not, in no small part because the OP hasn't provided a single entry from the bib file(s) in question. I honestly don't know if I've even understood the problem correctly. I went mainly by the OP's comment that "it would be better to list each of them in the references section". I interpreted this in a way that led to the answer I posted. If it turns out I was wrong, I'll have no problem deleting the answer.